# Are You Smart Enough to Solve This Rebus? Beat the Creator Challenge

Tags: knowledge, rebus

Here's a rebus:

[image]

The answer is a supervillain from a video game. The answer will become obvious if you solve some of the boxes. Therefore, in order to be upvoted, you must:

1. get the correct answer,
2. give an explanation.

I will upvote if it meets these criteria.

Partial answers are welcome.

**Note** **There has been an update to the rebus. I realized that a^2 might've been way too ambiguous
*An "I" has also been dropped in the last box for some apparent reason

Hint 1:

> Try spelling the pictures out

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Arkham Knight

thanks to the answer from Tweakimp.

> The first four letters are Arkh, which made it easier since this now it's definitely a Batman villain. The am comes from the opposite of Fm radio in the top right box. For the bottom box, we have the kn from knife with the letter i, and then we have a gh from ghost minus ost, the medical prefix for bone. I'm not sure where the last t goes though, unless the medical prefix is actually just os-.

Comment: Impressive. Well done! BTW [**os**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Os) is french for bone.

Comment: Nice! The "os" is also a word, it means bone.

Comment: How do you know that you should take only the first two letters from "knife"?

Comment: @MOehm Not really sure to be honest, once I knew it started with "arkh" I just googled it, saw arkham knight was a villain, and figured out how to make the letters fit. Not totally sure why the "I" is there either, since knife already starts with "kni".

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer:

> The creature in the top left is the [pokemon "Zoroark"](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zoroark_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).
>  I think we should treat each letter as a variable in a mathematical term.
>  *A² would add two As and /ZARA would remove these letters, leaving
>  "ooark" left in the top left cell.

Edit after the rebus has been updated:

> The As are now above Zoroark, which could make it Zaraark. Now remove Zara and we are left with **ark** in the top left cell.

Comment: Close, but now quite

Comment: i think you have to remove them in the correct order. so
zoroarkaa / zara = oroka

Comment: Nope thats not it either

Comment: You got the first box. Nice job. Now to solve the ridiculously confusing remaining squares